# Terminal icons blocked out Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: icons, 17.10

Ubuntu 17.10,GNOME in Xorg. My terminal application icons are partially blocked out.

[image]

This is true in Wayland, Xorg and Classic, all shell themes, all icon themes and all application themes. Annoying and at a loss as to what to do to fix it.

Comment: Sure is except that I am in Xorg. Hopefully someone will give some insight.

Comment: I have the exact same problem :(